# How do I negotiate alert boxes in Watir?

Tags: ruby, automation, watir

I am trying to create an automation script for a website using Ruby with
Watir.

I ran into a situation where I have to choose 'Yes' or 'No' in an
alert box. The problem is that I am not able to identify the alert box
as a component of the page so that I can obtain its identifier and use
it to select an option.

I found some information how to
create an alert box, but I need to navigate through one. Can
anyone help me out?

Comment: some alert boxes have to be dealt with at the OS level as they are modal and don't actually exist within the browser page.   In that case it helps to know your OS since different tooks are used to send keypress events at the OS level

Comment: it's easier to see what your situation is if there is a url to the website you are navigating. If that isn't available, you could provide the source of the page. it would save everybody from guessing.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a `confirm` box if you can choose two options ("OK" or "Cancel"). If you want to simulate clicking "OK", you have to put something like this before you trigger the confirm.

```
# return true for confirm to simulate clicking OK
b.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")
```

If you just have an `alert` with a single "OK" button, do this.

```
# don't return anything for alert
b.execute_script("window.alert = function() {}")
```

See [this page](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

The approach suggested by Austin Taylor may work fine, but I think that for a more general solution you need to deal with Popups at a OS level as Chuck suggests.

If anyone reaches this page seeking this sort of answer there are different solutions listed here: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups

Answer (score 0):

You can use these clean watir calls:

- browser.alert.ok
- browser.alert.close

See [Official Framework Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Alert) for more info.